# .Remove() not working in deleting a textbox with id in the form of an collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a hidden textbox with id in the form of a part of a collection. I use the ID in this way so as to have them bind to my model. This is the simplified version of my code.

```
<input id="Model.Bed[0].Id" name="Model.Bed[0].Id" type="hidden" value="bed1">
```

I am using Jquery to remove it but while it does not throw any error, it does not get deleted. This is my code.

```
$('#Model.Bed[0].Id').remove();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: $`('#Model.Bed[0].Id')` is invalid because of the brackets and dot in the selector, and if you had generated it correctly using `@Html.HiddenFor()` it would be `id="Model_Bed_0__Id"`. But `id` attributes have nothing to do with binding, so why are you even generating a complex `id` attribute like that manually. Just use a class name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jQuery selector returns 0 items because it is an invalid selector expression( `[` has a different meaning)

Try the name selector. This should work

```
 $("[name='Model.Bed[0].Id']").remove();
```

Keep in mind that it is allowed to have more than one element with same name attribute value. So use based on your DOM.

Also, If you have this input element generated in a loop and you have some button inside this loop for executing your remove code, you should consider using relative selectors. `closest()` and `find()` methods are handy in this case.

For example,

```
// Register click event with element with css class "someDeleteBtn"
$(".someDeleteBtn").click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
   $(this).closest(".containerDiv")  //get to outside container
          .find(".myHdnBed") // find the hidden input with this css class
          .remove();  // remove
});
```

Comment: Firstly, Thanks. Using name works fine. Secondly, I am looping through Model.Bed to display it on the table using <td class="col-sm-4">                                                @item.Name</td>. So any change I make to the table will not get bound to my model. Hence I have a list of hidden inputs to store each of the loop value and I name them accordingly to bind them to my model Model.Bed

Answer (score 1):

To escape special characters in an ID selector, you can use \ like so:

```
$('#Model\\.Bed\\[0\\]\\.Id').remove();
```

which works: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XpqJxV

Read more here: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-select-an-element-by-an-id-that-has-characters-used-in-css-notation/

In the end though, you really shouldn't have a value like that as an ID in the first place.